# Having trouble getting karma to work with Angular2

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, zone

I'm having trouble getting karma to work with Angular2. My project structure looks like this:

// Typescript sourcefiles:

/scripts

// Transpiled files

/wwwroot/app

// I copy my used node_modules to

/wwwroot/lib/node_modules

// My systemjs.config.js is in

/wwwroot

```
(function(global)

    var libFolder = 'lib/';
    var nodeModulesFolder = libFolder + 'node_modules/';
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app': 'app', // 'dist',
        // Vendor
        'rxjs': nodeModulesFolder + 'rxjs',
        'zone': nodeModulesFolder + 'zone',
        'jquery' : nodeModulesFolder + 'jquery/dist',
        'select2' : nodeModulesFolder + 'select2/dist/js',
        'nanobar' : nodeModulesFolder + 'nanobar',
        'qtip2' : nodeModulesFolder + 'qtip2/dist',
        'timeago' : nodeModulesFolder + 'timeago/dist',
        'highcarts' : nodeModulesFolder + 'highcharts',
        'highcarts-more' : nodeModulesFolder + 'highcharts',
        'chart' : nodeModulesFolder + 'chart',
        'solid-gauge' : nodeModulesFolder + 'highcharts/modules/',
        'bootstrap-tour' : nodeModulesFolder + 'bootstrap-tour/build/js',
        'password-analyzer' : nodeModulesFolder + 'custom',
        'moment' : nodeModulesFolder + 'moment',
        'nl': nodeModulesFolder + 'moment/locale',
        'ng2-charts': nodeModulesFolder + 'ng2-charts/components/charts'
    };

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': { main: 'main.js', format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'zone': { main: 'zone.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'jquery': {
            main: 'jquery.min.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'select2': {
            main: 'select2.full.min.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'nanobar': {
            main: 'nanobar.full.min.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'qtip2': {
            main: 'jquery.qtip.min.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'proigia_encryptie': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'timeago': {
            main: 'jquery.timeago.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'highcharts': {
            main: 'highcharts.src.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'highcharts-more': {
            main: 'highcharts-more.src.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'chart': {
            main: 'Chart.min.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'solid-gauge': {
            main: 'solid-gauge.src.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'bootstrap-tour': {
            main: 'bootstrap-tour-standalone.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'password-analyzer': {
            main: 'password-analyzer.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'moment' : {
            main: 'moment.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'nl' : {
            main: 'nl.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'ng2-charts': {
            main: 'charts.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    };

    var npmPackages = [
        '@angular',
        'rxjs'
    ];

    var ngPackageNames = [
        'common',
        'compiler',
        'core',
        'forms',
        'http',
        'platform-browser',
        'platform-browser-dynamic',
        'router'
    ];

    npmPackages.forEach(function (pkgName) {
        map[pkgName] = nodeModulesFolder + pkgName;
    });

    ngPackageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
        var main = global.ENV === 'testing' ? 'index.js' :
        'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js';

        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: main, defaultExtension: 'js' };
    });

    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };

    System.config(config);
})(this);}
```

And my karma.conf.js and karma-test-shim.js look like:

```
    // #docregion
module.exports = function(config) {

    var appBase    = 'app/';       // transpiled app JS and map files
    var appSrcBase = 'scripts/';       // app source TS files
    var appAssets  = '/base/app/'; // component assets fetched by Angular's compiler

    var dependencies = [
        '@angular',
        'rxjs'
    ];

    var configuration = {
        basePath: 'wwwroot',
        frameworks: [
            'jasmine'
        ],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-coverage'),
            require('karma-remap-istanbul'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-htmlfile-reporter')
        ],
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'coverage', 'karma-remap-istanbul'],

        preprocessors: {
            //'app/**/!(*spec).js': ['coverage']
        },

        // Generate json used for remap-istanbul
        coverageReporter: {
            reporters: [{
                type: 'json',
                subdir: '.',
                file: 'coverage-final.json'
            }]
        },

        remapIstanbulReporter: {
            src: 'coverage/coverage-final.json',
            reports: {
                html: 'coverage'
            },
            timeoutNotCreated: 5000
        },

        htmlReporter: {
            // Open this file to see results in browser
            outputFile: '_test-output/tests.html',

            // Optional
            pageTitle: 'Unit Tests',
            subPageTitle: __dirname
        },

        files: [
            // System.js for module loading
            {pattern: 'lib/system.src.js', included: true, watched: true},

            // Polyfills
            {pattern: 'lib/shim.min.js', included: true, watched: true},
            {pattern: 'lib/Reflect.js', included: true, watched: true},

            // zone.js
            {pattern: 'lib/node_modules/zone/zone.js', included: true, watched: true},
            {pattern: 'lib/node_modules/zone/long-stack-trace-zone.js', included: true, watched: true},
            {pattern: 'lib/node_modules/zone/proxy.js', included: true, watched: true},
            {pattern: 'lib/node_modules/zone/sync-test.js', included: true, watched: true},
            {pattern: 'lib/node_modules/zone/jasmine-patch.js', included: true, watched: true},
            {pattern: 'lib/node_modules/zone/async-test.js', included: true, watched: true},
            {pattern: 'lib/node_modules/zone/fake-async-test.js', included: true, watched: true},

            {pattern: 'lib/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false},

            {pattern: 'systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false},
            '../karma-test-shim.js',

            // transpiled application & spec code paths loaded via module imports
            {pattern: 'app/**/*.js', included: false, watched: true},
            {pattern: 'content/**/*.css', included: false, watched: true},

            // Paths for debugging with source maps in dev tools
            //{pattern: appSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false},
            {pattern: appBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false}
        ],

        proxies: {
            // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
            "/app/": "/base/app/",
            "/lib/node_modules/" : "/base/lib/node_modules/"
        },

        exclude: [],

        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        singleRun: false
    };

    dependencies.forEach(function(key) {
        configuration.files.push({
            pattern: 'lib/node_modules/' + key + '/**/*.js',
            included: false,
            watched: false
        });
    });

    config.set(configuration);
};
```

karma-test-shim.js

```
    // #docregion
// /*global jasmine, __karma__, window*/
Error.stackTraceLimit = 0; // "No stacktrace"" is usually best for app testing.

// Uncomment to get full stacktrace output. Sometimes helpful, usually not.
// Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity; //

jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

var builtPath = '/base/app/';

__karma__.loaded = function () { };

function isJsFile(path) {
    return path.slice(-3) == '.js';
}

function isSpecFile(path) {
    return /\.spec\.(.*\.)?js$/.test(path);
}

function isBuiltFile(path) {
    return isJsFile(path) && (path.substr(0, builtPath.length) == builtPath);
}

var allSpecFiles = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files)
    .filter(isSpecFile)
    .filter(isBuiltFile);

System.config({
    baseURL: '/base',
    // Extend usual application package list with test folder
    packages: { 'testing': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' } },

    map: {
        '@angular/core/testing': 'lib/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/common/testing': 'lib/node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler/testing': 'lib/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'lib/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'lib/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/http/testing': 'lib/node_modules/@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/router/testing': 'lib/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms/testing': 'lib/node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js'
    }
});

System.import('systemjs.config.js')
// .then(importSystemJsExtras)
    .then(initTestBed)
    .then(initTesting);

/** Optional SystemJS configuration extras. Keep going w/o it */
/*
 function importSystemJsExtras(){
 return System.import('systemjs.config.extras.js')
 .catch(function(reason) {
 console.log(
 'Warning: System.import could not load the optional "systemjs.config.extras.js". Did you omit it by accident? Continuing without it.'
 );
 console.log(reason);
 });
 } */

function initTestBed(){
    return Promise.all([
        System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
        System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
    ])

        .then(function (providers) {
            var coreTesting    = providers[0];
            var browserTesting = providers[1];

            coreTesting.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
                browserTesting.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
                browserTesting.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
        })
}

// Import all spec files and start karma
function initTesting () {
    return Promise.all(
        allSpecFiles.map(function (moduleName) {
            return System.import(moduleName);
        })
    )
        .then(__karma__.start, __karma__.error);
}
```

And I have a very simple .spec.file called 1st.spec.ts with:

```
describe('Testing math', () => {
    it('multiplying should work', () => {
        expect(4 * 4).toEqual(16);
    });
});
```

When I run

> karma start karma.conf.js

it starts, but I get:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I've been trying for days now, but can't seem to find a solution.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This isnt the real error, this is an error of the Jasmine file itself, to know what the real error is, use the chrome debugger and move slowly until you see the error builds up